Is the given below syntax for " if else" ladder in C++ correct?
if (condition1) 
{
  fun();
} 
else if (condition2) 
{
  fun2();
} 
else if (condition3) 
{
  fun3();
}

I have read articles online, and everywhere I see, at the end of the ladder an else clause is written.
In the code given above, I have else if in the end instead of else. I have doubts whether the above syntax that I have written is also correct.
Can we not end the ladder with else if, or is it necessary to end it with else only?

This syntax is correct.  You are not obligated to have a final else clause.

You could have just tested this code yourself to prove it is correct.

@JohnGordon Ya but I wanted to be sure about it. Just wanted to know other people thoughts on this.

@JohnGordon So, I can choose whether to use the last statement as ' else ' or 'else if ' . Am I correct ?

Technically you actually have an else clause in your statements. C++ doesn't have an "else if" statement, it's a separate else clause followed by an if statement. So your "ladder" could be written as if (condition1) { fun(); } else { if (condition2) { fun2(); } else { if (condition3) { fun3(); } } }. Any decent learning material should have taught this IMO.

@JohnGordon testing never proves correctness; at best it can demonstrate incorrectness.

@dd3012 What are condition1, condition2, and condition3?  Have concrete examples of what these conditions are.  Then you will know if else or else if is appropriate.  You can't simply just use dummy "conditions" for something like this -- the actual conditions are the most important thing to determine the if-else set up.

@PaulMcKenzie I just wanted to know does the syntax allow this ? I am expecting a general answer. It has nothing to do with the conditions.

@dd3012 It depends on what condition1-3 are and what the funs are and also if this if/else chain is done in a function or not. We can't tell you if it's correct without knowing that.

If what you wanted to see is if the syntax is correct, you could have written a small program to see this.  That's why I suspected that there has to be much more to the question than what you are asking, for example the logic of those if-else statements, not just the syntax.  If it's logic, then the conditons do matter.

So, I can choose whether to use the last statement as ' else ' or 'else if ' . Am I correct? Depends.  If the condition doesn't matter, then you can use else.  If the condition does matter, then you probably want else if(condition).

See this, and this.  One uses just else, while the other one uses if-else as the last condition.  Clearly the first one is logically incorrect, while the second one correctly does not call fun3.  So in both programs, the syntax is correct, but the first program is logically incorrect.

@dd3012 else is optional. That's the simple answer to the question you are asking I think

Is it possible that neither condition1, nor condition2, nor condition3 is true? In that case, you will need both else if. However, if it is guaranteed that if condition1  and condition2 is false, then condition3 must be true, then if (condition3) is redundant and it would be better to omit it.

I am curious what those conditions are because each branch you add will increase the complexity of (number of code paths through) your code which makes testing very hard.
